# HTML: How to make table cell border grow inwards

Tags: javascript, html

In a Javascript program (No CSS allowed, all styling is done in Javascript).

I wrote a program that increases the border thickness of a cell in a table when clicked (selected). I did this by setting the original border thickness to "thin" and then when clicked, changing the border thickness to "thick".

But when the cell is "selected", the width and height of the cell expands, which make it look like the table is shifting each time a cell selection is made.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Based on `excel` and google `sheet` , The border thickness is not changed when selected. The color changed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You said no css? But can you use JavaScript to set a css style dynamically? In that case,

```
element.style.boxSizing="border-box"
```

That will allow the border to be part of the layout calculations. 
But if you really mean no dynamically setting styles, then I am not sure what you mean by all styling is done in JavaScript.